# Maximum Frogs Saved

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, for-loop

There are N frogs, a snake, and a hole in a straight line. The snake is present at 0 and the hole is present at X. All the N frogs are present between the snake and the hole. The value of X and the positions of N frogs are passed as the input to the 13the program. Every second, a frog can move exactly 1 position to the right, but the snake always moves 1 position to the right after the frog's movement. If a frog reaches the hole, then it is safe from the snake. If the snake reaches any frog's position, then it eats all the frogs in that position. The program must print the maximum number of frogs that can be saved from the snake as the output.
**Note:** The snake never enters into the hole.

This is my code:

```
n=int(input())
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
b=int(input())

ak=[''] *(b+1)
ak[0]='S'
ak[b]='H'

for i in range(len(a)):
    ak[a[i]]+='F'

for j in range(len(ak)):
    if ak[j]=='':
        ak[j]='*'

print(ak)
```

```
My output:

[S,*,*,*,FF,F,*,F,F,F,H]
```

But I need this Output

```
Input:

6
4 7 5 8 4 9
10

Output:

3

Explanation:

Here N=6, X=10, and the given 6 integers are 4 7 5 8 4 9. 
The maximum number of frogs that can be saved from the snake is 3.

One of the possible ways to save 3 frogs is given below.

At T=0, [S,*,*,*,FF,F,*,F,F,F,H]
At T=1, [*,S,*,*,FF,F,*,F,F,*,HF]
At T=2, [*,*,S,*,FF,F,*,F,*,F,HF]
At T=3, [*,*,*,S,FF,F,*,F,*,*,HFF]
At T=4, [*,*,*,*,S,F,*,*,F,*,HFF]
At T=5, [*,*,*,*,*,S,*,*,*,F,HFF]
At T=6, [*,*,*,*,*,*,S,*,*,*,HFFF]

S- Snake
H- Hole
F- Frog
*- Empty Space
```

I don't know how to iterate and replace that *, S, F. Please explain to me the logic behind this problem.

Comment: It seems the problem is missing some information. What prevents all the frogs from moving right every turn thus saving every frog?

Comment: You can only move one frog every turn @trent

Comment: Even I thought about that... But they are trying to save every frog 1 by 1 I guess...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the assignment: `The program must print the maximum number of frogs that can be saved from the snake as the output`  
No need to explain your solution you just need to return the number of saved frogs

Comment: But I don't the logic bro like how to find the number of saved frogs. @Thekingis007

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I sorted the list of frogs positions in a descending order, after that I iterate over the sorted list and check if the distance between the hole and the frog is smaller than the distance between the snake and the hole, if that's the case I add +1 to `ans` and add the distance between the frog and the hole to the `snake` value.

Code:

```
n=int(input())
a=[int(i) for i in input().split()]
x=int(input())

a.sort(reverse=True)

snake = 0
ans = 0

for frog in a:
    if x-frog < x-snake:
        ans +=1
        snake += (x-frog)
        
print(ans)
```

Input:

```
6
4 7 5 8 4 9
10
```

Output:

`3`

Explanation:

```
sorted list  = [9,8,7,5,4,4]
```

for the first frog `10-9 < 10-0` so `ans += 1` and `snake += (10-9) = 1`

for the second frog `10-8 < 10-1` so `ans += 1` and `snake += (10-8) = 3`

for the third frog `10-7 < 10-3` so `ans += 1` and `snake += (10-7) = 6`

Now you can see that the snake is already at position `6` and the frogs at position `4` and `5` didn't move so they will not be saved.

so finally `ans = 3`

Comment: Thanks, bro!! @TheKingis007 Now, I understood the logic