# How to find the number of saved fish?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find the number of fish that are saved from the fisherman.

Condition:

```
fish will move exactly one position to the right
fisherman moves one position to right after fish movement
```

The fisherman at position '0' and house at position "X".
Note if the fish reaches the fish house the fish is safe other wise the fisherman will catch the fish.

Input:

```
1st line represents no of fishes(N)
2nd line represents position of fishes
3rd line represents the position of house of fishes(X)
```

Example Input:

```
6
4 7 5 8 4 9
10
```

Example output:

```
3
```

My code:

```
n=int(input())
l=list(map(int,input().split()))[:n]
k=int(input())
l1=[i for i in l if i>n and i<=k]
print(l1)
print(len(set(l1)))
```

My input:

```
5
2 2 1 2 3
4
```

My output:

```
 0
```

Needed output:

```
2
```

What mistake have I made? Is my logic is correct?

Comment: Fish or [frogs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71169612/18238422), which one is it?

Comment: if i understand it correctly from your described conditions the fisherman will always be one behind. but I guess the fisherman catches the fish if they have the same position but that will never occur if the fisherman moves after the fish moved